# If mod_expires is used in .htaccess will modified files be downloaded by the client

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, http, cache, apache-2.4

I'm trying to employ caching to speed up the response time of a website. Most of the documentation I have read suggests setting expiration to +1 month from time of access as follows:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
```

I'm concerned that if I update a css file that the client will not get the updated file.

Is it possible to ensure the client downloads a new version of a file if it is modified?

Any help much appreicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concern is correct - clients whose browsers have retrieved the file will typically not receive the updated version until 1 month after they accessed it unless they happen to have cleared their browser cache or they do a reload on the page.

One way around this is when you update the CSS file, change the HTML that references it to have ?v=2 or ?v=3 etc. at the end of the link tag's href attribute (i.e. after the .css).  Browsers view that as a unique URL and will thus download the new copy, yet it will point to the same physical .css file on your server.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css" />
```

becomes

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css?v=2" />
```